# Change div's background from one color to another like gradient

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change background of div from red to green depending on variable value. If var value is 1, the background is red. But as the value increases to 1000, div background becomes greener. Like it goes through red-to-green gradient. How can I do this not using jQuery?

P.S. variable value increases every 2 seconds btw

Comment: The value is changed with JavaScript? And how much increases every 2 seconds?

Comment: yes, it changes with JavaScript, 1 second every 2 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following approach with `RGB` values for colors in vanilla JS.

```js
var INTERVAL = 2, //Change this to 2000 to make it change every 2 seconds
    MAX = 1000, //MAX value
    _r = 255,
    _g = 0;

var i = 1,
    _rPart = (255/MAX),
    _gPart = (128/MAX);
    
var _handler = setInterval(function(){
   
   _r = _r - _rPart;
   _g = _g + _gPart;
   
   document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + 
                                                                 Math.floor(_r) + 
                                                                 ", " + 
                                                                 Math.floor(_g)
                                                                 + ", 0)";   
   if(i == MAX){    
      clearInterval(_handler);
   }
   
   i++;
   
}, INTERVAL);
```

```css
#container{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Assume that you have an array with a color gradient (you can create one [here](http://www.perbang.dk/rgbgradient/)).

```
var colorGradient = ['red'...'dark green'];

makeAGradient = function(index) {
  var count = 0;
  var intervalId = window.setInterval(function(){
    $('#my_div').css('background', colorGradient[count]);
    count +=1;
    if (count==index) window.clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, 2000);
}
```

I'll try something like the code above.